# how to store unique values in sessions using laravel?

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

i want to store unique tasks in sessions of a related job. 
i am doing like this.
 Its storing tasks in sessions but not with unique validation. i am also using ajax but i think there is not relation of ajax to store unique value in session.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'job_task' => ['required' , 'unique:jobtasks,task_type'],
]);

Session::push('jobtasks', $request->all());

return view('admin.jobs.inc._taskTable');
```

This the image what i am doing

[image: This the image what i am doing]

Comment: You never checked whether the validation failed or not.

Comment: my question is that how can we store a unique value from a form to session

Comment: in my case its not working. if i am doing like this and i am not sure its a better way or not.

Comment: What does `$this->validate()` method call return you?

Comment: its validating a field of form

Comment: its just a condition if something in form field then validate it if not then show some message.

Comment: its a built in function in laravel

Comment: I know that. I am asking what does var_dump($this->validate()) in your code return you? Sessions will store unique values but first they need to pass the unique validation rules you have specified.

Comment: $validate = $this->validate($request,
                [
                    'job_task' => 'required',
                    
                ]
            );
            dd($validate);  outPut: array:1 [▼
  "job_task" => "3"
]

Comment: its not running with unique validation and returning 500 internal server error

Comment: Add a `temp` (boolean) field to the table. If jobs become permanent (which I presume is a user action), set `temp` to false. When the person logs out, run a simple cleanup script before the `Auth::logout();` to remove every input of that user where `temp` is true. You may have to run a general clean up from time to time for temp=true inputs older than 2 weeks or so, to keep your table clean.

Comment: @MuhammadAbuBakar for 500 internal server error, check your error logs in `storage/logs` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to people who tried to help me but i used javascript to store unique values in the session with the help of condition on ajax.
I declared array and stored values in session and as well as in the array if user someone again want to save same value i check it in array and then so on.